# Cursor Image is not working when entering area in image

Tags: jquery, html, css, cursor

I am using own designed cursor as shown below.

```
$("div").css('cursor','url(../graphics/system/mybg.cur),auto');
```

but when cursor enters in to defined area of an image, cursor image is changing to normal pointer. This is happening only in chrome.
Can any one tell how fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around your image URL.

`$("div").css('cursor','url("../graphics/system/mybg.cur"),auto');`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bwCLn/

If that's not working, check your image URL, because the above JSFiddle is working for me on Chrome.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is working on normal part of the image. As i said when cursor enters in to a defined area with co-ordinates, cursor image is still missing.

Comment: Then you need to post more of your code, because the posted line isn't your problem